# How to assign ",p" to org-agenda-priority?

Tags: spacemacs

I tried

`(spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'org-agenda ",p" 'org-agenda-priority)`

I don't see this reflected in the key map.  What is the correct way?

This is on Spacemacs 0.300.0, rev. ccd6c48d4.

Thank you,

Comment: I'm a bit confused as well about how to use that function in spacemacs, but it may not be necessary in this case?  `org-agenda-priority` is already bound to `,` in `org-agenda` mode.  If you're trying to set this key binding specifically on the menu you get from the major mode map (`,` or `M-RET`) you probably want to bind a key in the `spacemacs-org-agenda-mode-map`

something like this:

`(define-key spacemacs-org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "p") 'org-agenda-priority)`

Comment: On my version of spacemacs, the keys in agenda mode are a, c, d, i, and s.  No `,' key binding.

Comment: those are the key bindings in the `spacemacs-org-agenda-mode-map` which you get to by first typing the major mode leader key which is `,` in evil mode or `M-RET` in many modes.  You won't see the `,` binding for org-agenda in the which-key popup.  if you really want to put it there then i can explain how though

Comment: I accomplished what I wanted with the following: `(spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'org-agenda-mode "p" 'org-agenda-priority)`.  Your suggestion `(define-key spacemacs-org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "p") 'org-agenda-priority)` worked as well.

Comment: would you like me to write up an answer for this?  I think I could probably summarize the discussion here :) there are a few confusing things going on with keybindings between vanilla Emacs, Evil mode, and Spacemacs bindings.